# SQL Indexing: None, Single Column, and Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, indexing

How does indexing work in SQL and what benefits does it provide? What reason would there be for not indexing? And what is the difference between indexing a single column vs. indexing multiple columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does indexing work in SQL and what benefits does it provide?

When you index columns you express your intent to query the indexed columns in conditional expressions, such as equality or range queries. With this information the storage engine can build a structure that makes such queries faster, often arranging them in tree structures. B-trees are the most common ones, but a lot of different structures exists, such as hash indices, R-tree indices for spatial data etc. Each structure is specialized in a certain type  of look ups. For instance, hash indices are very fast for equality conditions, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE type = "example";
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id = X;
```

B-trees are also fairly quick for equality look ups, but their main strength is that they support range queries:

```
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE id > 5 AND id < 10
SELECT * FROM example_table WHERE type = "example" and value > 25
```

It is VERY important, however, when you build B-tree indices to understand that the tree is ordered in a "left-to-right" manner. I.e, if you build a B-tree index (lets call it A) on {type, value}, then you NEED to have a condition on the type-column in order for the query to be able to utilize the index. The example index can NOT be used in a query where the condition solely depends on value. 
Furthermore, if you mix equality and a range condition, make sure that the equality columns are listed **first** in the index, otherwise the index can only be partially used.

> What reason would there be for not indexing?

If the selectivity of the index is low, then you might not gain much over a table scan. say for instance that you have an index on a field called gender. Then the selectivity of that index will be low, since a lookup on that index will return half the rows of the original table. You can read a pretty simple explanation on selectivity here, and the reasoning behind it: http://mattfleming.com/node/192

Also, maintaining an index has a cost. For each data manipulation the index might need restructuring. So keeping the amount of indices to the minimum required to perform well on the queries against that table might be desirable.

> What is the difference between indexing a single column vs. indexing multiple columns?

Once again, it depends on the type of queries you issue. Indexing a single column gender might not be a good idea, since the selectivity is low. When the selectivity is high then such an index makes much more sense. For instance, indices on the primary key is a very good index, since the selectivity is high (actually, it is as high as it gets. Each key in the index corresponds to exactly on record), and indices on columns with unique or highly different values (such as slugs, password hashes and what not) are also good single column indices.

There is also the concept of covering indices. Basically, each leaf in an index contains a pointer into the table where the row is stored (unless the index is a clustered index. In this case the leaf is the record). So for each index hit, the query engine has to fetch the corresponding table row, increasing the number of I/O-operations. Since I/O is extremely slow, you want to keep this to a minimum. Now, lets say that you often need to query for something, and also fetch some additional columns, then you can create a covering index, trading storage space for query performance. Example: Let's find the name and email of all users who has joined in the last 6 months (assuming MySQL):

With index on {joined_at}:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email 
FROM users 
WHERE joined_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
```

Query explanation:

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE       users  ALL   test           NULL NULL     NULL 873   Using where
```

As you can see in the `type`-column, the query engine resorted to a full table scan, since the index selectivity was too low to be worthwhile using in this query (too many results would be returned, and thus followed into the table, costing too much in I/O)

With index on {joined_at, first_name, last_name, email}:

```
id  select_type table  type  possible_keys  key   key_len ref  rows Extra
1   SIMPLE      users  range test,test2     test2 8       NULL 514  Using where; 
                                                                    Using index
```

Now, since all the information that is necessary to complete the query is available in the index, the query engine evaluates that it is much better to use the index (with 514 rows) instead of doing a full table scan.
So as you can see, by using covering indices we can speed up queries for partial selects of a table, even if the selectivity of the index is quite small.

Answer (score 2):

> How does indexing work in SQL

That's a pretty open question but basically databases store a structure that enables faster look up of information. That structure is dependent on the implementation but its typically a type of tree.

> what benefits does it provide?

Queries that are SARGable can be significantly faster.*

> What reason would there be for not indexing?

Some data modification queries can take longer and there is storage cost to indexes but generally speaking, both these considerations are negligible.

> And what is the difference between indexing a single column vs. indexing multiple columns?

There isn't much difference but sometimes people create covering indexes** that index mutliple columns to increase the performance of a specific query.

---

*SARGable is from Search ARGument ABLE. Basically if you do `WHERE FOO > 5` it can be faster if FOO is indexed. On the other hand `WHERE h(FOO) > 5` probably won't benefit from an index.

** If all the fields used in the SELECT JOIN and WHERE of a statement are also in an index a database can retrieve all the information it needs without going back to the base table. This is called a covering index. If all the fields were in separate indexes it would only use the ones for the joins and where and then go back to the base table for the columns in the select.

Comment: Thank you for quick informative answer. Do you think you could elaborate on a few of those for me please? What does SARGable mean? And what is the difference between indexing several columns as single indexes vs having one index of those same several columns together?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include expansions on the ideas of SARGable and Covering indexes